# What's the song on episode 24 of season 3 of Boku no Hero Academia when the Big Three is entering the class?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What's the name of the song at 21:25 on episode 24 of season 3 of *Boku no Hero Academia* when the Big Three is entering the class?

I can't find it, even uncle Google couldn't help.

Comment: Finally i found it, the name of the song is Katsuki and Izuku.

Comment: Since you found the answer, feel free to post it as an official answer to your question! It makes it easier to see than a comment for anyone else viewing your question.

Answer (score 2):

The song is called Katsuki and Izuku. Here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8Up_g4oEoA) to it. It is on the 3rd season's OST.